# Data final em D/M/A, sobre determinado numero de dias

Tags: php

Preciso que quando o usuário digitar uma quantidade de dias, a função deve calcular e exibir no formato (DD/MM/AAAA) o dia final somando os dias recebidos a partir de hoje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a maneira que utilizo:

```
$qtdeDias = 5;
echo strftime('%d/%m/%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), (date('d')+$qtdeDias), date('Y')));
```

Leia mais sobre a funções na documentaçao:

- [strftime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php)
- [mktime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php)

Espero que ajude, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser calcular a data, desconsiderando o horário, uma alternativa (a partir do `PHP 5.1`) é utilizar a flexibilidade de [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$qtde = 46;
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("today midnight +$qtde days"));
```